# ExecJS:RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a Javascript runtime Docker app

Tags: javascript, ruby, docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to build a container rails app using **Docker**. In my Gemfile,  `execjs` gem is already present. However, on running the server i get the below error

`ExecJS:RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a javascript runtime`

Upon digging further, I found out adding gem `therubyracer` or `mini_racer` solves the issue. however, with that addition I get the below error.

`Unable to load application: LoadError: Error relocating /usr/local/bundle/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.so: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found - /usr/local/bundle/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.so`

Please help

Comment: you would need to have `node` or some other js environment installed If I 'm not mistaken

Comment: To elaborate on what @NikosM. said, you need to install `nodejs` in your Docker image, for example on Debian/Ubuntu you would need to run `apt install nodejs` or on Alpine `apk add nodejs`.

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch. I needed nodejs installed in my docker image. `apk add nodejs` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is raise because of `therubyracer` gem is not actively maintain by owner.

I also faced same issue when move to `ruby:2.6.5-slim` to `ruby:2.6.5-alpine` docker image. After few hours googling I found the solution to solve it.

install `nodejs` and `python v2.7` package and add gem in your Gemfile
`gem 'libv8-alpine', '~> 6.7', '>= 6.7.288.46.1'`
and remove `gem 'therubyracer'` from Gemfile.

Refefences:
[libv8-alpine](https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8-alpine)
[enter link description here](https://github.com/rubyjs/libv8/issues/270#issuecomment-573063347)

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade `execjs` gem.

On modern Macs, the JSC lives in a different place. I was getting this error message when setting up our Rails app on a new M1 Mac mini running Big Sur.

Upgrading to `execjs` 2.8.0+ fixed the issue for me:

`Gemfile`

```
gem "execjs", "2.8.1"
```

You can see the merge commit here:

https://github.com/rails/execjs/pull/98